# SCCM 2007 query to select users belonging to listed AD groups

Tags: query, sccm-2007

Can somebody advice me on WQL query to select all users from specified AD groups? I tried to do this through query builder but without success.
I'm going to use these selecter user to further select those of them who don't have some particular software installed.
Any advice on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Query Rule**

- Resource Class: User Group Resource

**Criteria**

- Attribute Class: User Group Resource
- Attribute: Name Operator "is equal to"
- Value: YOURDOMAIN\YOURGROUP